# Session not working on one PHP page

Tags: php, session

What is wrong with this login script? I have a modal-style iframe login box which is `/login.php` and I have a `/index.php`.

After logging in, the login.php redirects to the index.php, but I don't see the username. just `Hello Guest`. When I try to login it says `you, username, are already logged in`.

login.php:

```
<?php session_start(); require_once('connections/Main.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You, '.$_SESSION['username'].' are already logged in.</div>';
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> to the page you were viewing before this.</li>";

    exit();
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php session_start(); 
   require_once('connections/Main.php'); 
     ?>

<div> Hello <?php   if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
          echo $_SESSION['username']; }
                    else{ echo 'Guest'; } ?></div>
```

Comment: It does not redirect back, it says 'go back in history'. A lot of browsers cache the DOM, and going back wouldn't result to a new request on your server. If you link to `/index.php` rather then that javascript thingamayig, do you get the desired behavior?

Comment: yes it redirects the iframe to index.php and does show the correct username but how could i make the main page redirect

Comment: If you are in a `frame` (brrr), either set `target="top"`, or possibly `onclick="window.top.location.reload(true)"`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**start your session with this.**

```
$_SESSION["im_going_in"]=true; 
$_SESSION["username"]=$username;//get data from db.
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["im_going_in"]) {
?>

  <?=strtoupper($_SESSION["username"])?>// welcome dear bla bla...

<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `session_start()` twice, which is unnecessary. And once you are logged in, have a session variable `logged_in` set `true`. Then use

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in']){
 //Do what you want for the logged in user
}
```

To be true, you can do all this in one single login.php. Have something like this:

```
//if reached from login form
if ($_POST['email']){
  //validate the user
  // if validates, log him in by:
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
  //do other fancy database save stuff
 }
//else show him login form
else{
  <form>
   //<input />.. etc
  </form>
}
```